# How can I create python custom types from C++ using native Python/C API?

Tags: python, c++

Explanation is defined below:

I have defined a new Python type named "Ex1".

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject * int_id;
    int * value;

} Ex1;
```

With this type in mind and all appropriate methods generated and validated in Python interpreted (it works pretty well). I want to be able to create a python object of the new Ex1 Type from C++ backend. A typical structure of what I need is:

```
int main 
{
     // Create Ex1 Object.
     Ex1 Example;

     // Call PythonC-API method to include Ex1 Object into the python interpreter.
     // ¿Any function-method from Python API to perform this task?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I managed to solve this problem using python docs:

https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html

First of all it is necessary to define the appropiate methos as is described in the python docs ([1](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html)) . Assuming the PyType created has two attributes (varp1 and varp2):

```
PyObject * create_Ex1(vartype1 var1, vartype2 var2)
{
    PyObject * pInst = PyObject_CallObject((PyObject *)&Ex1Type, NULL);
    ((Ex1*)pInst)->varp1 = var1;
    ((Ex1*)pInst)->varp2 = var2;    
    return pInst;
}
```

and

```
static int Ex1_init(Ex1 *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{   
    // On init return -1 if error
    self->varp1= NULL;
    self->varp2= NULL;
    return 0;
};
```

This is defined on the static PyTypeObject Ex1Type as is described in the python docs ([1](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html)).

Then the object is created and initialized using this line:

```
PyObject* Ex1_obj = create_Ex1(var1, var2);
```